# One-to-One Relationship - How to fix Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a user profile using Django Rest Framework, but constantly receiving

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `MyUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'MyUser' object has no attribute 'user'.
```

Is it related to one-to-one relationship and the fact that my User model is defined by email? Is there a way to help it?

Here are my **models.py**:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=300,
        unique=True
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='email address'
    )
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

class Profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pictures') #blank - true
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'bio', 'image')
```

and **views.py**:

```
class ProfileView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(user)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line

```
serializer = ProfileSerializer(user)
```

You are passing a user object, but your serializer expect a profile object.  It should work if you do this:

```
serializer = ProfileSerializer(request.user.profile)
return Response(serializer.data)
```